# HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR in Websphere 8.5..5

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws, websphere-8

During the configuration of my application in WAS 8.5.5 in profile2, I have got his error. Expecting clues to track this error. Strange thing is, I have the same configuration and application in profile1 is working as expected. Doing the same in profile2 is not working and thrown the following error. Any guess on this ??

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
  <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
     <faultcode xmlns:ns5="http://idm.vignette.com/">ns5:Server</faultcode>
     <faultstring>org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <ns2:exception class="javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
           <message>org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.</message>
           <ns2:stackTrace>
              <ns2:frame class="com.abc.edf.server.common.MyHandler" file="IDMHandler.java" line="209" method="handleException"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.abc.edf.server.common.MyHandler" file="IDMHandler.java" line="104" method="handleMessage"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.abc.edf.server.common.MyHandler" file="IDMHandler.java" line="41" method="handleMessage"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor" file="HandlerProcessor.java" line="336" method="callHandleMessageReverse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor" file="HandlerProcessor.java" line="207" method="callHandlersResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ServerSOAPHandlerTube" file="ServerSOAPHandlerTube.java" line="161" method="callHandlersOnResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube" file="HandlerTube.java" line="160" method="processResponse"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="639" method="__doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="588" method="_doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="573" method="doRun"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="470" method="runSync"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="295" method="process"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="515" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="285" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="143" method="handle"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="155" method="doGet"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="189" method="doPost"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="76" method="doPost"/>
              <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="754" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="847" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="1230" method="service"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="779" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper" file="ServletWrapper.java" line="478" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl" file="ServletWrapperImpl.java" line="178" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager" file="WebAppFilterManager.java" line="1071" method="invokeFilters"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper" file="CacheServletWrapper.java" line="87" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer" file="WebContainer.java" line="914" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer" file="WSWebContainer.java" line="1662" method="handleRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink" file="WCChannelLink.java" line="200" method="ready"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="459" method="handleDiscrimination"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="526" method="handleNewRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="312" method="processRequest"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink" file="HttpInboundLink.java" line="283" method="ready"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback" file="NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java" line="214" method="sendToDiscriminators"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback" file="NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java" line="113" method="complete"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener" file="AioReadCompletionListener.java" line="175" method="futureCompleted"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture" file="AbstractAsyncFuture.java" line="217" method="invokeCallback"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture" file="AsyncChannelFuture.java" line="161" method="fireCompletionActions"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture" file="AsyncFuture.java" line="138" method="completed"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler" file="ResultHandler.java" line="204" method="complete"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler" file="ResultHandler.java" line="775" method="runEventProcessingLoop"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2" file="ResultHandler.java" line="905" method="run"/>
              <ns2:frame class="com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker" file="ThreadPool.java" line="1864" method="run"/>
           </ns2:stackTrace>
        </ns2:exception>
     </detail>
  </S:Fault>
```

Comment: recommend at least posting `com.abc.edf.server.common.MyHandler`, specifically the `handleMessage()` method. This appears to be adding DOM nodes to the SOAP message that is not allowed.  Perhaps logic there will shed light on something different across your WAS profiles.

Comment: Hi Scotth, can u guide me to upload a file in stackoverflow. That method is very long and want to upload as a file.

Answer (score -1):

in wsdl file definitions
remove the wsam tag
Addressing

located in the WEB-INF folder

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJjIT.png)